# Liferay Service Builder - Database Persistence

Tags: database, liferay, persistence, data-persistence

i understand that persistence layer is where you store your data, and that not all data is persisted in the same manner -- some use databases, some use XML, some use a remote service.

What then is (as a verb) Database Persistence? I'm studying Liferay Service Builder and came across a definition that "it automates creation of interfaces and classes for database persistence"

In other words, What is database persistence in the context above in simple plain English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifera service builder generates classes that can be used to do CRUD operations for database entity only. So its referred as database persistence.